# Can OCMockito stub a method that takes a `const void *` parameter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmockito

My `MessageSerializer` class has a method whose signature looks like this:

```
- (Message *)deserialize:(const void *)buffer length:(NSUInteger)length;
```

Can I use OCMockito to stub it? Where `serializer` is my mock serializer, the compiler approves of all these following forms in my test method:

```
[given([serializer deserialize:[data bytes] length:[data length]]) willReturn:message];
[given([serializer deserialize:(__bridge const void *)anything() length:[data length]]) willReturn:message];
[given([serializer deserialize: CFBridgingRetain(anything()) length:[data length]]) willReturn:message];
```

... but none of them cause the mock to return "message" to the class under test when `deserialize:length:` is called.

Comment: Taking another look a few hours later, OCMockito will quite happily return me what I requested from the above stub, as long as I pass my mock in to unit under test in the first place (i.e., the problem was entirely my fault and I keep getting screwed by the fact that messaging nil in Objective-C is entirely valid.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCMockito doesn't support `const void *` parameters at this time. I'd recommend making a hand-rolled stub.